# Spring Boot session attribute is null in REST controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, session

I am developing a social Twitter app for which I am using Spring Boot 2.2.2. I am following the instructions here https://careydevelopment.us/2017/05/24/implement-twitter-login-solution-spring-boot/.

I have just modified my code to be more REST oriented instead of RedirectView(as done in above link)

```
    @PostMapping("/getToken")
    public ResponseEntity<TwitterTokenResponse> getToken(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        Twitter twitter = getTwitter();
        String callbackUrl = "http://localhost:3000/settings";
        RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackUrl);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);

        *//setting twitter attribute in session*
        request.getSession().setAttribute("twitter", twitter);
        String twitterUrl = requestToken.getAuthorizationURL();
        TwitterTokenResponse twitterTokenResponse = new TwitterTokenResponse(requestToken.getToken(), requestToken.getTokenSecret(), true, 0L, null);
        log.info("Authorization url is " + twitterUrl);
        log.info("Request token is " + requestToken);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(twitterTokenResponse);
    }

    @PostMapping("/twitterCallback")
    public ResponseEntity<TwitterTokenResponse> twitterCallback(@RequestParam(value = "oauth_verifier", required = false) String oauthVerifier, @RequestParam(value = "denied", required = false) String denied, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        if (denied != null) {
            log.error("Could not get token from Twitter! Access denied");
            return null;
        }

        *//Getting twitter attribute back from session but it is null*
        Twitter twitter = (Twitter) request.getSession().getAttribute("twitter");
        RequestToken requestToken = (RequestToken) request.getSession().getAttribute("requestToken");
        AccessToken token = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, oauthVerifier);
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("requestToken");
        TwitterTokenResponse twitterTokenResponse = new TwitterTokenResponse(token.getToken(), token.getTokenSecret(), true, token.getUserId(), token.getScreenName());
        log.info("Access token is " + token);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(twitterTokenResponse);
    }
```

As can be seen in getToken() method I am setting the twitter variable in session and trying to get the same variable from session in twitterCallback() method. the twitter attribute I am getting from the session is always coming null. Any reasons why it is like that and what can be done to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Did you check sessionid in both states?
I mean check the sessionid in getToken and then check it in twitterCallback, and please be sure that they are the same.

Comment: Hi @MehrdadHosseinNejad, indeed the session ids are different in both the sessions. I fixed my session timeout to spring.session.timeout=30m but it is still not working.

Comment: So obviously your problem is because of having two different sessions in two different requests. (The session must be the same at two requests). are you using spring security in your app?

Comment: Hi yes I am using spring security and currently the session create policy is STATELESS. I tried it with IF_REQUIRED as well but it did not work either. I am using JWT for securing rest endpoints

Comment: If you're using JWT, that means your server must not keep states. (it must be stateless), but you are making it stateful with setting attributes to sessions, It doesn't make any sense at all. I suggest you save the twitter token to the client JWT, not the session. (Keep your server stateless)

Answer (score 0):

**First** -  please check your `sessionid` in both controller methods, they must be the same. If they are not, so obviously you have a new session that means there is no "twitter" attribute on it.

**Second** - There may be a time period between your requests (between the first request to get token and second to fetch it), that can cause the session to kill and generate a new one that doesn't have "twitter" attribute anymore, So Please check your session timeout also.